# Swift - UIButton animation doesn't work when title has a variable

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to animate an UIButton. The UIButton is hidden and I want to slideUp it to show it.

At the same time, i'm changing its title with a counter "Number: (self.number)"

The title changes but the animation doesn't work. If I try to change the title to a normal string like "title", it works...

My code:

```
var number = 0

func moveBtn(){
    self.number = self.number + 1
    var yPos = 100

    let myCaption: String = "Number: (\(self.number))"
    self.button.setTitle(myCaption, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) {
        self.button.frame.origin.y = yPos
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you've created the constraint in the interface builder you connect it to the code through an IBOutlet and try this:

```
var number = 0
@IBOutlet weak var BottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    func moveBtn(){
        self.number = self.number + 1
        var yPos = 100

        let myCaption: String = "Number: (\(self.number))"

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
            self.button.frame.origin.y = yPos
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.BottomConstraint.constant = 0
            self.button.setTitle(myCaption, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        })
    }
```

Comment: May I ask for clarification, why do you set the constant to 0? What happens if another functions updates the layout? `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` If you update the layout wouldn’t that put the button at the bottom of the page?

Comment: I have set the constant to 0 so that the button remains in the bottom of the page. If you change the tittle of the button when the animation ends the button returns to the position set out in constraints. The correct is to change the constraint to the position where the animation ends.